# MySQL - AFTER INSERT TRIGGER does not run UPDATE query?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Using MySQL 5.1.x

Trying to add a trigger to a table:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER group AFTER INSERT ON dataTable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE dataTable SET groupName = mid(longName,1,4) WHERE groupNAME IS NULL;
END$$
```

When I insert a record there is no update made.  Is there a syntax error?  Or can I not run the Update query on the after insert event?

UPDATE:  There are 2 triggers on this table (a AFTER INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `MySQL` trigger, you cannot invoke `DML` on the table that fires the trigger.

Comment: Note to self: DML = Data Manipulation Language

Comment: Thanks @Quassnoi - that definitely is annoying...off to another solution.